# pyspark Column is not iterable using withColumn

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Why am I getting a column is not iterable error when using pyspark?

```
cost_allocation_df = cost_allocation_df.withColumn(
    'resource_tags_user_engagement',          
     f.when(
         (f.col('line_item_usage_account_id') == '123456789101', '1098765432101') &
         (f.col('resource_tags_user_engagement') == '' ) |
         (f.col('resource_tags_user_engagement').isNull()) |
         (f.col('resource_tags_user_engagement').rlike('^[a-zA-Z]')),
    '10546656565').otherwise(f.col('resource_tags_user_engagement'))
)
```

Comment: You first expression contains three values `(f.col('line_item_usage_account_id') == '123456789101', '1098765432101')` but the comparing operator can handle only one value on each site (i.e. two in total).

Comment: You can return only one value from When clause and one from otherwise unless you nest it. You can do either F.when(condition, return value).otherwise(return value) or F.when().when().when().otherwise() or F.when(condition, F.when(condition, return value). otherwise(return value)).otherwise(return value) . Please ignore the typos and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have a direct comparison from a column to a `value`, which will not work. You will have to make a column of that `value` using `lit()`

Try to convert your code to :

```
cost_allocation_df = cost_allocation_df.withColumn('resource_tags_user_engagement',          
 f.when(
       ((f.col('line_item_usage_account_id') == f.lit('123456789101')) | 
       (f.col('line_item_usage_account_id') == f.lit('1098765432101'))) & 
       (f.col('resource_tags_user_engagement') == f.lit('') ) |
       (f.col('resource_tags_user_engagement').isNull()) |
       (f.col('resource_tags_user_engagement').rlike('^[a-zA-Z]')), '10546656565'
       ).otherwise(f.col('resource_tags_user_engagement')))
```

Comment: *You will have to make a column of that value using `lit()`* - this is not true. `f.col('line_item_usage_account_id') == '123456789101'` will work fine.